# Nested objects null checking

Tags: java, spring-boot, nullpointerexception

I know many ways how to check on nested objects for a `NullPointerException`, as for Java 8  the simplest is to apply the `Optional<param>`.
or to use a simple if code such as

```
if(foo.bar() != null && foo.getBar().getObject()!=null){
    foo.getBar().getObject().getWhatever();
}
```

well my question is is there an easy way to do so in one method without knowing the names of the inner classes/methods

to be more clear i have a code which is like this

```
contract.getContactInfo().getPosition()
contract.getEntitledPerson().getEmail()
```

and i want to do something like this for an example

```
excel.setCell(name1,contract.getContactInfo().getPosition());
excel.setCell(name2,contract.getEntitledPerson().getEmail());
```

if its for only 2 nested objects or only 2 setters that's fine but get it for a 50 excel cells with sometimes 5 or 6 nested objects its a real nightmare to do so

something lets say like the setCell method

```
public setCell(String name,Object object){
     return object; // make sure no nested object is null
}
```

i hope my question is clear enough. keep in mind i cant simply change the nested objects since its legacy code and being used in a lot of places! any ideas ?

Comment: I don't believe there is something that can do this task, mostly because you can't generalize as you should know what exaclty to put in a particular cell.

Comment: @NiVeR not sure if i got it right, lets say everything will be a string in the end.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As you mentioned yourself in the question, use `Optional`, but it's more lenghty.

```
excel.setCell(name1, Optional.of(contract).map(Contract::getContactInfo).map(ContactInfo::getPosition).orElse(null));
excel.setCell(name2, Optional.of(contract).map(Contract::getEntitledPerson).map(Person::getEmail).orElse(null));
```

Which is more easily read when formatted like this:

```
excel.setCell(name1, Optional.of(contract)
                             .map(Contract::getContactInfo)
                             .map(ContactInfo::getPosition)
                             .orElse(null));
excel.setCell(name2, Optional.of(contract)
                             .map(Contract::getEntitledPerson)
                             .map(Person::getEmail)
                             .orElse(null));
```

If your goal is smallest code, you could just catch the `NullPointerException`. It's a bit of a hack, in my opinion, but it'll do the trick.

First, a helper method:

```
public static <T> T nullGuard(Supplier<T> supplier) {
    try {
        return supplier.get();
    } catch (@SuppressWarnings("unused") NullPointerException ignored) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you wrapper the expression in question:

```
excel.setCell(name1, nullGuard(() -> contract.getContactInfo().getPosition()));
excel.setCell(name2, nullGuard(() -> contract.getEntitledPerson().getEmail()));
```

Comment: this is fine enough, but i wanted to do everything in the setCell method so the code is still readable you wont believe how unreadable it is with just the get.get.get.get inside a set with more than 50 sets

Comment: and also using Optional.of will throw an exception Optional.ofNullable would be better in this case, right ?

Comment: @YamenNassif Only if `contract` itself can be null. --- As for the *"do everything in the setCell method"*, then make *it* take the `Supplier` argument and catch the `NullPointerException`, so call becomes `excel.setCell(name1, () -> contract.getContactInfo().getPosition());`, i.e. from callers perspective, all you need to add is the `() ->` to defer execution until inside the `setCell` method.

Comment: I accepted the answer since its correct, but i am still looking for something to apply on the setCell for the code readablitiy

Comment: @YamenNassif What readabililty? How is this not readable? `excel.setCell(name1, () -> contract.getContactInfo().getPosition());`

Comment: @YamenNassif Sorry, didn't get that. What was readable? Not readable? Before what edit?

Comment: just ignore it ^^, i was typing from mobile at that moment so i might have missed something, anyhow its working i applied the last way nullGuard couldnt do it in the setCell since i had some concatenations in some fields