# How to avoid redundant method calls when checking the result first for null?

Tags: java

I found in my code areoccuring pattern where I call the same method multiple times:

```
private String doSomething(MyObject obj) {
   if (myObj == null
      || myObj.getA() == null
      || myObj.getA().getB() == null
      || myObjg.getA().getB().getC() == null) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error message...");
   } else {
      return myObj.getA().getB().getC();
   }
}
```

As you can see, I call getA(), getB() and getC() each multiple times. I'd like to avoid that, but still check for null. What's a good approach to avoid these redundant method calls?

Comment: save `myObj.getA()` in a local variable. But `getA().getB().getC()` is a code smell anyway and should be removed / refactored.

Comment: what about `private String doSomething(MyObject myObj) {
    try{
        return myObj.getA().getB().getC();
    }catch (NullPointerException e){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Error message...");
    }
}`

Comment: @YCF_L That's not equivalent, as C == null originally results in an exception, and in your example it doesn't.

Comment: Check my question on almost the same thing, and check the answer it really helped. https://stackoverflow.com/q/50800955/2724879

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html), and especially its [`map()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) method, are well suited for this kind of situation:

```
private String doSomething(MyObject obj) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(myObj)
        .map(MyObject::getA)
        .map(MyObject::getB)
        .map(MyObject::getC)
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Error message..."));
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Technically, you shouldn't worry about repeatedly calling these getter methods. The getters should be **really** small methods, so *when* the JIT figures at runtime that it is worth optimizing them, they will be inlined in machine code anyway, giving you maximum performance. And when the JIT finds "this is not worth optimizing", then guess what: then it is not worth optimizing. When your getter methods are too big to be inlined, then you got a *real* problem sitting there anyway.

But the real answer here is: simply do not violate the [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) in the first place.

It is simply bad practice to allow for *such* kind of changing. The code you are presenting **knows** that an A has a B has a C. Therefore this code depends on **three** classes A, B, C. And your classes A and B can't be changed *without* breaking clients. From that point of view, such kind of "fluent" interfaces `getA().getB().getC().doSomething()` should very much be avoided.

The real answer here is to put `doSomething()` on class A and *hide* all potential dependencies behind it.

Comment: I generelly agree with you mentioning the LoD, but the structure of these classes have to be like that because they represent DTos that I receive by JSON.

Comment: @FischerLudrian I updated my answer to talk about the optimising part, too. Hope that helps.

Comment: @FischerLudrian Beyond that, it *might* be an option to enhance your DTO classes to at least *hide* this chaining. What prevents you from simply **adding** a `doSomething()` method on your class A?

Answer (score 1):

This "pattern" is not the problem. It's a **symptom** of the problem. The **real problem** is that you have written code based around the use of procedural data holders containing chain after chain of nullable fields.

The solution, then, is to write code [that uses proper objects](https://www.yegor256.com/2014/09/16/getters-and-setters-are-evil.html).

Comment: Yes, but what if I get these data in this form over a REST interface?

Comment: @Fischer You map your JSON data you receive onto real objects instead of simple DTOs and then the same advice applies again.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred alternative to your pattern is to explicitly check at each access stage. This results in a much richer and more detail error management at the expense of a few extra indents.

```
private String doSomething(MyObject myObj) {
    if(myObj != null) {
        A a = myObj.getA();
        if(a != null) {
            B b = a.getB();
            if(b != null) {
                return b.getC();
            } else {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("myObj.a.b is null");
            }
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("myObj.a is null");
        }
    } else {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("myObj is null");
    }
}
```

Note that this deep nesting of `if` shape is considered a symptom of the **Arrow Antipattern** which generally indicates that you should do some refactoring. Remember that this is just an *indicator* of that problem, it is NOT the problem itself.